# Ant junit batchtest

Tags: java, ant, junit

I have my junit test classes.I am running these class with ant.I am using batchtest attribute with parameter includes="**/* Test *.class" but i have classes with name like * test * that includes no test method and when i run it gives error "no tests found".Is there a option like if no test in the class then skip?

Comment: Why do you have test classes with no test methods in them?

Comment: they are not test classes.But their name contains test.

Comment: Example of a file name that contains test, that cannot be renamed to not contain test please.

Comment: MailerTest and MailMessageTestObject

Comment: You can't refactor those names?  What is wrong with `TestMailer` and `TestMailMessage`?  Notice how the names begin with Test

Comment: i can but exists a lot of class

Comment: I would recommend taking the time now to refactor the names and enforce the new naming convention this will save you hours of pain later.  Also the rename process is pretty trivial in an IDE such as Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question you need to supply a better pattern.

Potential solution:

Refactor all legitimate test classes to **BEGIN** with the prefix `Test`  and than change the ant script to this:

```
includes="*/Test*.class"
```

Why do you have classes with the name "Test" in them that aren't tests?  I highly recommend following a naming convention that puts `Test` at the beginning and removing `test` from your file names that are in fact not tests.